# Using Combine Publisher with AsyncSequence

Tags: swift, async-await, combine

I'm currently migrating code that was using Combine Publisher to an AsyncSequence.  I previously used this alongside `@Published` search query that user could type in and now trying to "combine" that search term with `AsyncSequence` based data source such as following (using `values` to convert the search query to `AsyncSequence` as well).  However, I'm only seeing the `flatMap` code being executed once initially.

```
@MainActor
class FantasyPremierLeagueViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var playerList = [Player]()
    @Published var query: String = ""
    
    private let repository: FantasyPremierLeagueRepository
    init(repository: FantasyPremierLeagueRepository) {
        self.repository = repository
        
        Task {
            let playerStream = asyncStream(for: repository.playerListNative)
            
            let filteredPlayerStream = $query
                .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
                .values
                .flatMap { query in
                    playerStream
                        .map { $0.filter { uery.isEmpty || $0.name.contains(query) } }
                }
                .map { $0.sorted { $0.points > $1.points } }
                
            
            for try await data in filteredPlayerStream {
                self.playerList = data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code pushed to branch and can also be viewed in https://github.com/joreilly/FantasyPremierLeague/blob/kmp_native_coroutines/ios/FantasyPremierLeague/FantasyPremierLeague/ViewModel.swift

Comment: Just glancing over the code in the question, I'd suggest this: Your `filteredPlayerStream` is a Combine pipeline. But it has no extended lifetime; it is purely a local variable within your task. Therefore it doesn't live long enough to produce more than one value (frankly I'm surprised that it produces any values at all).

Comment: I *think* `filteredPlayerStream` should be an `AsyncStream` (given use of `values` there)....but your point I think is still valid re. lifetime....will try that shortly, thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind I could be totally wrong! I didn't run any code.

Comment: Ran into similar issues in a project where we cannot use swift-async-algortihms (Xcode 13.x project). The lifetime issue is a good hint. There's no completion or cancellation, but this would make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like this can be done in a much cleaner way using `combineLatest()` from new Swift Async Algorithms package (https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms).

```
Task {
    let playerStream = asyncStream(for: repository.playerListNative)
        .map { $0.sorted { $0.points > $1.points } }

    for try await (players, searchQuery) in combineLatest(playerStream, $query.values) {
        self.playerList = players
            .filter { searchQuery.isEmpty || $0.name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(query) }
    }
}
```